# What's the best development workflow for building an NPM package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package

I am currently trying to package a javascript library.  So far I have the package set up as follows:

- `npm build` puts everything in a `build` directory
- `main` attribute in `package.json` points to the entrypoint in `build` that exports my libary's top-level API.
- I am able to include the package in another project by adding `"{packagename}": "file:{pathToMyPackage}"`

My question is this:  I am now trying to troubleshoot my package from the other project.  Each time I make changes, I must rebuild the project to reflect the changes AND I must `rm -rf node_modules/{packagename} && npm install` on the project that is using the local package.

I know I can add some kind of watcher to the package that will build when new files are saved, but how can I make the higher-level project monitor changes to the local package it is using?  Is there a magic tool for this sort of thing, or do people just add custom npm scripts while they are doing development on a dependency?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is `npm link` (https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link).

### Example Usage:

`package-a` depends on `package-b`.

Navigate to `package-b`'s project folder on the command line. Run `npm link`.

Now navigate to `package-a`'s folder and run `npm link package-b` (You may need to run `npm uninstall package-b` first; not sure).

This will create a symlink in `package-a/node_modules/package-b` to `package-b`'s working directory. Any changes you make there will be reflected in the `node_modules` for `package-a`.

Just keep this in mind; if you break something while working on `package-b`, `package-a` may break too.